# What causes Smoking and burnt earth wire when try start my outboard motor? strong compression.engaging bell/cog doesn’t return

Tags: starter

Throw out bell of starter not returning and pinion spins inside bell[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: A poor connection or damaged wire?

Comment: Which earth wire is burning?  Can you add a photo?

Comment: Is there a thick earth wire connected that is as least as thick as the wire that goes from the battery positive to the starter?

Comment: Previous owner went for like a 8mm cable to a 10-12 mm cable and soldered at a join about 18 inches from solenoid. Will attach pic.

Comment: Just added pics of cables

Comment: Replace those joined cables.

Comment: Is it the 8mm cable that is burning?

Comment: Yes the 8 mm is the one that has melted through

Comment: If the 8mm cables are original, it would suggest to me that the starter is faulty and is drawing too much current.

Comment: No the original cable is the larger of the 2